# How can I prevent nested JSON, by e.g. transforming the nested objects to a JSON string in the JSON?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this kind of class:

```
class Thing
{
    // ...
    public IDictionary<string, dynamic> Parameters { get; set; }
}

//...
void Test()
{
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    thing.Paramaters["counting"] = new List<int>{1,2,3};
    thing.Parameters["name"] = "Numbers";
    thing.Parameters["size"] = 3;

    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);
}
```

And I'd like to `result` to contain this:

```
{
    "Parameters" :
    {
        "counting" : "[1,2,3]",
        "name" : "Numbers",
        "size" : 3
    }
}
```

I have taken a look at [`IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) and believe I should special case `string`s on deserialization to check if there's JSON in them, and special case all class objects to convert them to a string. I just have no idea where to begin doing that.

In the end the problem is this: the data structure I'm plugging this JSON into does not work with nested JSON. It only knows about the basic data, i.e. string and numbers, at this "sublevel". I know, terrible, get rid of this evil data structure. Well, I can't. So I need to be creative and I thought this might be a way out. If anyone can think of a better way, I'd much appreciate it!

**EDIT** The answers below special case the `List<int>` example I put in `Test`, but it's still a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` which can contain everything. That's what I mean with nested JSON: any JSON, not just an array.

Comment: So what's the result at the moment? And why are you treating numbers differently to lists? (In the former case you're using the regular JSON representation; in the latter case you're converting the whole thing to a string.)

Comment: Your JSON is invalid - it should be `"Parameters" : { ...` - note the quotation and the colon. Is this also what you want or is it a mistake?

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis Yes, that's a typo, I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ideally, I'd just serialize the thing as is, and have a nice tree of JSON stuff in the serialized string. But unfortunately, the data structure I need to plug this into does not accomodate nested JSON (it's a custom written, euhm, thing), so I need to be creative, and thought this might be a way out.

Comment: Well it's unclear exactly what the requirements are then, as it can apparently handle numbers but not lists. You'll need to make the question really clear before we can help you - otherwise it'll be an exercise in frustration.

Comment: @Jon I amended the question. It can only handle numbers and strings at that level, but the serialized class can contain anything, hence I thought using a JSON string for the anything might work out. Sorry for the frustration I already might have caused.

Comment: This might help you: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/ -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the problem is not so much about writing a `List` to a `string`, but more about a way to create JSON with only two levels of depth - having everything beyond that a string.

I don't think an [`IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) would work for this, you should implement a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) instead. The basic idea would be that it iterates over your object's children, then over their children, checking their type. If they're an array or an object - it would replace them with a serialized string.

**Implementation:**

```
class TwoDepthJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jo = JObject.FromObject(value);
        foreach (var property in jo)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in property.Value)
            {
                var paramVal = parameter.First;
                if (paramVal.Type == JTokenType.Array || paramVal.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    paramVal.Replace(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramVal.ToObject<object>()));
                }
            }
        }
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JToken.ReadFrom(reader).ToObject(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
thing.Parameters["counting"] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
thing.Parameters["name"] = "Numbers";
thing.Parameters["size"] = 3;

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing, Formatting.Indented, new TwoDepthJsonConverter());

// Results:
// {
//   "Parameters": {
//     "counting": "[1,2,3]",
//     "name": "Numbers",
//     "size": 3
//   }
// }
```

Of course, performance could be improved - for example writing to the writer manually instead of parsing to a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and then manipulating it. However this should be a good starting point.

Comment: This looks a lot like what I had in mind, thanks! Wouldn't `ReadJson` need similar logic to differentiate the json string (representing an array/object) from a non-json string (representing only numbers or strings)?

Comment: Yes it would! However your question was only about serialization - I assumed you don't need deserialization. Knowing the general process, you could just reverse the algorithm, although you would find deserialization much harder, as you'd have to somehow differentiate nested stringified JSON from regular strings.

Comment: ok, just making sure ;). I though I'd check by just trying a deserialization if the string started with `[` or `{` and try and go from there. I'll try and see where I get.

Comment: @rubenvb You could try to deserialize every string you find with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, on failure catching a `JsonReaderException` and keeping the original string - it should work for most cases. I'll leave that as homework to you :-)

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking. Not wholly efficient but meh, if it works it works. It's for small bits anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `JsonConverter` and instead of using `List<T>` you would use a custom class that inherits from `List<T>`..

The reason for it needs to be a custom `List` is that if you register a `JsonConverter` for `List<T>` you would not be able to get normal array serialization.

Following http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/ I was able to make this.

```
public class CustomListSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var values = (IEnumerable)value;
        var items = values.Cast<object>().ToList();
        var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);

        writer.WriteValue(s);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable));
    }
}


[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomListSerializer))]
internal class CustomList<T> : List<T>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("counting", new CustomList<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5 });
        parameters.Add("users", new CustomList<User>() { new User { Name = "TryingToImprove" }, new User { Name = "rubenvb" } });
        parameters.Add("name", "Numbers");
        parameters.Add("size", 4);

        var thing = new
        {
            Parameters = parameters,
            Name = "THING",
            Test = new List<int>() {  1, 2, 3}
        };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing));
    }
}

internal class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which will return

```
{
   "Parameters": {
       "counting": "[1,2,3,5]",
       "users": "[{\"Name\":\"TryingToImprove\"},{\"Name\":\"rubenvb\"}]",
       "name": "Numbers",
       "size": 4
   },
   "Name": "THING",
   "Test": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: I'd need it to work on future types as well, and not limit it to a specified set of types I can convert in this manner. Pretty much a check: if(simpleStringOrNumber) doNormalSerialization else serializeObjectAndQuoteString. I'm just not wrapping my head around the JsonConverter thing.

Comment: i got this from your code `{"Parameters":{"counting":[1,2,3],"name":"Numbers","size":3}}`

Comment: It does work on nearly every type I have tried.. I have updated the code and the result. @rubenvb

Comment: I am not sure how you get that output? My array have a length of 4

Answer (score 0):

This is working -

```
internal class CustomJsonFormatter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Thing));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = value as Thing;

        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            var local = prop.GetValue(data, null) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            foreach (var key in local.Keys)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(key);

                if (local[key].GetType() == typeof(List<int>))
                {
                    string s = "[";
                    var arr = ((List<int>)local[key]);
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
                    {
                        s += arr[i].ToString() + ",";
                    }
                    writer.WriteValue(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) + "]");
                }
                else { writer.WriteValue(local[key]); }
            }

        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        writer.WriteEndObject();            
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new CustomJsonFormatter());

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing, settings);
```

produces

```
{"Parameters":{"counting":"[1,2,3]","name":"Numbers","size":3}}
```

Comment: This will only work if if is a `List<int>`, my answer would also work with `string`'s and `object`'s